# Retrieving multiple XML elements with LINQ by attributes

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Given this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<queryableData>
  <table displayName="Shipments" dbName="Quotes">
    <foreignKey column="CustomerId" references="CustomerRegistration"/>
    <foreignKey column="QuoteStatusId" references="QuoteStatus"/>
    <fields>
      <field displayName="Quote Charge" dbColumn="QuoteCharge" type="Number"/>
      <field displayName="Total Weight" dbColumn="TotalWeight" type="Number"/>
    </fields>
  </table>
  <table displayName="Customers" dbName="CustomerRegistration">
    <fields>
      <field displayName="First Name" dbColumn="FirstName" type="Text" />
      <field displayName="Last Name" dbColumn="LastName" type="Text"/>
    </fields>
  </table>
</queryableData>
```

I want to get a list of an anonymous object type containing the DisplayName, DbColumn and Type fields for the "Quotes" table only.

I am able to get a list of both tables with the following LINQ to XML code:

```
    var xml = XElement.Load(@"C:\Sandbox\queryable.xml");

    // Tables
    var tables = from el in xml.Elements("table")
                        select new 
                        {
                            Text = el.Attribute("displayName").Value,
                            Value = el.Attribute("dbName").Value
                        };
```

But I am not sure how to get the fields value where the dbName attribute of the table element is "Quotes".  The closest I've gotten is a list containing a list of values, instead of a list of anonymous objects with one item having the dbColumn/displayName pair:

```
var columns = from el in xml.Elements("table")
            where el.Attribute("dbName").Value.Equals("Quotes")
            select new LookupData { 
                Text = el.Elements("fields").Elements("field").Attributes().Where(x => x.Name == "displayName").Select(x => x.Value),
                Value = el.Elements("fields").Elements("field").Attributes().Where(x => x.Name == "dbColumn").Select(x => x.Value)
            };
```

so I expect this in a list:

**LookupData #1**

Text: "Quote Charge"

Value: "QuoteCharge"

**LookupData #2**

Text: "Total Weight"

Value: "TotalWeight"

and I'm getting this instead:

**LookupData #1**

Text: List containing two strings: [0] = "Quote Charge", [1] = "Total Weight"

Value: List containing two strings: [0] = "QuoteCharge", [1] = "TotalWeight"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
var result = xml.Elements("table").
    Where(el => el.Attribute("dbName").Value.Equals("Quotes")). // 1
    SelectMany(el => el.Elements("fields").Elements("field")).  // 2
    Select(f => new 
                {
                    Text = f.Attributes().Where(x => x.Name == "displayName").
                        Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                    Value = f.Attributes().Where(x => x.Name == "dbColumn").
                        Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault()
                }
           ) // 3
;
```

Explanation:

1. We select the elements where `dbName == "Quotes"`
2. Of everyone of those elements, we select all `field` elements and flatten the result with the usage of `SelectMany`. The result will be an `IEnumerable<XElement>`.
3. For every field, we select an anonymous type with the `Text` property set to the value of first attribute named "displayName" and the `Value` property set to the value of the first attribute named "dbColumn"

The problem with your approach was basically, that you put step 2 inside the creation of the anonymous type. Or in other words: You created one anonymous type instance per "Quotes" element, not per "field" element.